# Kendo grid export date format incorrect

Tags: javascript, c#, excel, date, kendo-grid

when I try to export the excel from Kendo grid, the date format is incorrect.

This Warranty_Start_Date is nullable in my table column, and below is the template for grid's column.

```
    customColumns.push({
       title: customHeaders[i],
       field: headers[i],
       width: 150,
       template:
           "#= " + headers[i] + " ? kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(" + headers[i] + "), 'dd/MM/yyyy') : 'N/A' #",
    });
```

and for the grid, I enable the excel export function and trying to customize the format for certain column:

```
            var grid = $("#gridHardwares").kendoGrid({
        excel: {
            fileName: "excelfile.xlsx",
            allPages: true,
            filterable:true
        },
        excelExport: function(e) {
            var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];

            for (var rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < sheet.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
                var row = sheet.rows[rowIndex];
                for (var cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row.cells.length; cellIndex ++) {
                    if (cellIndex >= 9 && cellIndex <= 11)
                    {
                        row.cells[cellIndex].format = "yy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
                    }
                    if (cellIndex >= 13)
                        row.cells[cellIndex].format = "0.00";
                }
            }
        },
```

I don't understand because this two decimal places format is working fine but the date format is not.
The export result in excel:
[date is not in readable format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYOhU.png)

I also tried this method where it keeps the column template, but I hit an error for "replace undefined"

```
            excelExport: function(e) {
            var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
            var template = kendo.template(this.columns[13].template);
            for (var rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < sheet.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
                var row = sheet.rows[rowIndex];

                for (var cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row.cells.length; cellIndex ++) {
                    if (cellIndex >= 9 && cellIndex <= 11)
                    {
                        var dataItem = {
                            Warranty_Start_Date: row.cells[13].value
                        };

                        row.cells[13].value = template(dataItem);
                        row.cells[cellIndex].format = "yy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
                    }
                    if (cellIndex >= 13)
                        row.cells[cellIndex].format = "0.00";
                }
            }
        },
```

[error occur when export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxy5I.png)

Maybe this template method is not suitable in my case, I don't know. But is there any other ways to convert this date string /Date(1382544000000)/  into proper "dd-MM-yyyy" format? Need help badly :(

Comment: Nothing to do with your issue, but "yy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" will produce an ambiguous time as 12 hour without am/pm. Consider "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" instead. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok fine, the solution is just setting this field type to "date". Crazy.
[image]

Comment: I had the same problem and mine was due to parse function, removing the function did the job.